# How I can read specific words from txt files in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

im trying to find a word in a txt file, something like a string input. Im new to python and pycharm so I don't know what to do, I want something where with an input I can find a word or a name in a txt file.

I got a txt file with names and values, and I want to make an input where when I type in a name, that is on the list, it brings on everything thats on that line.

Understand? please help me :(

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: `ctrl + F` should show a find pop up box

Comment: Python have [very good documentation](https://docs.python.org/) including good tutorials. Start there and you should learn all you need to know. Also, this issue is a pure Python issue, it have nothing to do with the editor or IDE you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Things to do is
1: Open the text file you want to search for
2:Then check the each line in the text file with your search word
3:If your search word found in the line,print the line

Code is:

```
a = With open('filename.txt','r')
For b in a:
       c = "Your search word"
       If c in b:
           Print b
```